# Why do I keep getting an error when trying to install "pip install ball" on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, installation, pip

```
(venv) (base) matthewpark@Matthews-MBP game % pip install ball
Collecting ball
  Using cached Ball-0.2.9.tar.gz (348 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/matthewpark/PycharmProjects/game/venv/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/xg/q1x0qzfn35588jpnk5b253zm0000gn/T/pip-install-smw00u2m/ball/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/xg/q1x0qzfn35588jpnk5b253zm0000gn/T/pip-install-smw00u2m/ball/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/xg/q1x0qzfn35588jpnk5b253zm0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-y5008n2o
         cwd: /private/var/folders/xg/q1x0qzfn35588jpnk5b253zm0000gn/T/pip-install-smw00u2m/ball/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/xg/q1x0qzfn35588jpnk5b253zm0000gn/T/pip-install-smw00u2m/ball/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        import numpy as np
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
(venv) (base) matthewpark@Matthews-MBP game %
```

Comment: The error massage says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`. You need to have `numpy` installed before installing ball

Answer (score 0):

How to get the most of error messages in python

```
(venv) (base) matthewpark@Matthews-MBP game % pip install ball
Collecting ball
  Using cached Ball-0.2.9.tar.gz (348 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/matthewpark/PycharmProjects/game/venv/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/xg/q1x0qzfn35588jpnk5b253zm0000gn/T/pip-install-smw00u2m/ball/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/xg/q1x0qzfn35588jpnk5b253zm0000gn/T/pip-install-smw00u2m/ball/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/xg/q1x0qzfn35588jpnk5b253zm0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-y5008n2o
         cwd: /private/var/folders/xg/q1x0qzfn35588jpnk5b253zm0000gn/T/pip-install-smw00u2m/ball/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/xg/q1x0qzfn35588jpnk5b253zm0000gn/T/pip-install-smw00u2m/ball/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        import numpy as np
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
(venv) (base) matthewpark@Matthews-MBP game %
```

Unfortunately the most relevant parts of error messages are at the end.

- First search for the error type, like `SystaxError` or `TypeError`, here `ModuleNotFoundError`
- Then look for the message after the error type

In your case the information to solve your problem is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`. Before installing `ball` you have to install numpy.

```
pip install numpy
```